# How to create 2 threads and to print Thread id's alternatively and numbers from 1 to 20?

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, pthreads

Code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_t tid[2];
void* fun(void* ptr) 
{
    int i = *((int *) ptr);
    int self_id;
    self_id=pthread_self();
    printf("Thread %u  ",self_id);
    printf("printing %d \n", i);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL;
}

int main() 
{
    int i=0,j=1,k;
    for(j=1;j<21;)
    {
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {   
            pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,fun,&j);
            sleep(1);
            j++;
        }

    }
    for(j=1;j<21;)
    {
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
            j++;
        }
    }
        pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So if the 2 threads are t1 and t2 and their thread id's are say 1023 and 1024, then the output should be as

```
            Thread 1023 printing 1
            Thread 1024 printing 2
            Thread 1023 printing 3
            Thread 1024 printing 4

            and so on till printing 20
```

But the output of my code is

```
            Thread 1023 printing 1
            Thread 1024 printing 2
            Thread 1025 printing 3
            Thread 1026 printing 4

            and so on till printing 20
```

The thread id's are not alternating. How to make the thread id's alternate.

Comment: You're creating more than 2 threads, is that what you want?

Comment: raj indent your code. Use 4 spaces for indenting the body of a function, for example.

Comment: [You're welcome.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html)

Comment: @rakib I just want to create 2 threads

Comment: In that case, only create two threads.

Comment: ..and then look at the hundreds of duplicates that demonstrate how to do this utterly pointless task of serializing two threads by tossing around a 'go' unit between two semaphores.

Comment: Also, excerpt from the docs: *Performing a return from the start function of any thread other than the main thread results in an implicit call to pthread_exit(),* ... Apart from that, how do you think these threads are going to *alternate*, if you are killing them?

Comment: check you're for loop, your creating 20 threads their.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for(j=1;j<21;)
{
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {   
    pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,fun,&j);
    ...
```

you create 20 * 2 threads, which explains the number of threads you witness.

In order to create two threads, you should only create two threads, like:

```
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{   
  pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,fun,&j);
  ...
```

i.e., without the outer loop. Moreover, you have to modify `fun()` to print 10 times (so 2 * 10=20). Now the tricky part is to make `fun()` of first thread synchronize with second thread, if you really need to define the order of output messages. However, this kills parallelization.

---

PS: You need to `#include <unistd.h>` for `sleep()`.

Comment: Hmm @AndrejsCainikovs I would say 20!

Comment: But then the output would appear only twice but  20 times is required

Comment: The problem here is there are only 2 threads and 20 lines to print out. So when pthread_create() is invoked automatically the function is executed. So if the thread is created only twice only 2 lines would be printed.

Comment: You have to modify your function void* fun(void* ptr), it needs to print 20 times, and it must be synchronized with other threads.

Comment: Can you please post the code? I have been trying this question for a lot of time.

Comment: @raj are you familiar with 'for' loop constructs, eg, those running from 0 to 19 inclusive?  Use on in each of the ttw threads.

Comment: @raj please modify your question, I can post sample solution code to your ploblem

Comment: @PawełDymowski I would say 10 each, right?

Answer (score 0):

From the question what I can understand is, you want two threads, alternatingly printing 1 to 20.

First of all, you are spawning 40 threads, as gsamaras pointed out, because the outer loop iterates 20 times, and the inner one iterates 2 times. Therefore you have to just spawn 2 threads as pointed out by gsamaras.

Adding to it, if you want to alternate the printing, you must have some synchronisation, else the order of printing in a file (stdout in this case) is undefined. I would recommend using condition variable to alternate between the threads in this case to achieve your goal.

If you are relatively new to POSIX threads or threading, I would recommend you go through this: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: 'I would recommend using a mutex in this case to achieve your goal. A thread should lock the thread prints a line, and releases before returning.' - won't work.

Comment: @MartinJames: Can you explain a bit more and help me fix my response?

Comment: If you lock up the printf with a mutex, there is no guarantee that, when the mutex is released, the other thread will get the mutex.  It's quite possible that the thread that released it will just acquire it again after looping round.

Comment: You're right, sorry about that. Condition variable then.

Comment: Thanks, I could do it with the help of mutex.

Comment: But I still have a doubt after reading about mutex. When we use a mutex why at all should we use pthread_join() method since mutex would anyways prevent concurrent access to shared resources?

Comment: Actually the same question was asked prevoiusly but i did not understand the answer